# Moving cursor to the next input using down arrow key on dynamically created input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with dynamically created rows and input, what  I would like to do is when the down/up arrow is pressed, the cursor can move to the next or previous text input without using the mouse. I have tried one but seems not to work for me.

Table with dynamically generated rows

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" class="dave-table" id="TabsTabeUniformity">
            <tbody><tr><th id="counter">No of rows: 3</th>
            </tr></tbody><tbody>                
            <tr>
                <td height="53"><div align="center">No.</div></td>
                <td valign="middle" align="center"><p align="center">Tablets (mg)</p></td>
                <td><button id="addRow">+ Add Row</button></td>
            </tr>
           <tr><td><div align="center">1</div></td>
                       <td><input type="text" tabindex="1" required="" class="num" size="25" name="tabdata[]" id="tcsv1"></td>
                       <td><button id="remRow">-Remove</button></td>
                   </tr><tr><td><div align="center">2</div></td>
                       <td><input type="text" tabindex="1" required="" class="num" size="25" name="tabdata[]" id="tcsv1"></td>
                       <td><button id="remRow">-Remove</button></td>
                   </tr><tr><td><div align="center">3</div></td>
                       <td><input type="text" tabindex="1" required="" class="num" size="25" name="tabdata[]" id="tcsv1"></td>
                       <td><button id="remRow">-Remove</button></td>
                   </tr><tr>
                <td><div align="center">Average</div></td>
                <td><input type="text" readonly="" name="average" id="av1"></td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>

            <input type="hidden" id="tabStatus" name="tablet">          
        </table>
```

The javascript I am trying to use

```
$(document).on('keydown','#TabsTabeUniformity > tbody tr.num',function (e) {
    if (e.which === 40) {

        $(this).closest('td').nextAll().eq(1).find('.num').focus()
    }
 });
```

Any suggestions is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace your javascript with this:

```
$(document).on('keydown','#TabsTabeUniformity > tbody tr .num',function (e) {
    if (e.which === 40) {
      $(this).parents("tr").next("tr").find('.num').focus();
    }
 });
```

also note the whitespace between `tr` and `.num` in the first line, because in your code, you searched for `<tr>` with class `num` and not its children

Answer (score 0):

Could also use this without referring to the class or id, or if you add cells/inputs to a row:

```
 $("input").keydown(function (e) {

    var cellindex = $(this).parents('td').index();

    if (e.which == 40) {
              $(e.target).closest('tr').nextAll('tr').find('td').eq(cellindex).find(':text').focus();
    }
    if (e.which == 38) {
    $(e.target).closest('tr').prevAll('tr').first().find('td').eq(cellindex).find(':text').focus();
    }

});
```